# maatwebsite excel not download directly

Tags: laravel-5.4, maatwebsite-excel

I used maatwebsite excel in laravel. 
export excel return raw data to browser instead download.
But i refresh page it automatically downloaded correctly. 
below first raw data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZUFs.png)

how to download directly?

Answer (score 0):

I understood this reason after full day research. my used admin panel using pjax container. So download request couldn't work. I added target='_blank' to download actionlink and it worked.